# Jav 8 Splash Screen.getSplashScreen() always returns null. Jar is invoked via Java Web Start using JNLP file

Tags: java-8, splash-screen

```
manifest file
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.6.5
Created-By: 20.1-b02 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)
SplashScreen-Image: Images/Splash.gif
Permissions: all-permissions
```

Application-Name: DealEntry Application

```
The path to the splash screen is correct
```

On SplashScreen.getSplashScreen() null is returned. Somehow it is not working in my application. Altough I tried a demo where it worked.

```
    import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

    import javax.swing.*;
     import java.awt.*;
     import java.awt.*;
     import java.awt.event.*;
     import java.awt.*;
     import java.awt.event.*;

     public class Splash extends Frame implements ActionListener {
        static void renderSplashFrame(Graphics2D g, int frame) 
        {
        final String[] comps = {"foo", "bar", "baz"};
        g.setComposite(AlphaComposite.Clear);
        g.fillRect(120,140,200,40);
        g.setPaintMode();
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.drawString("Loading "+comps[(frame/5)%3]+"...", 120, 150);
    }
    public Splash() {
        final SplashScreen splash = SplashScreen.getSplashScreen();
```

Always returns null when the jar os executed using javaws.

```
    if (splash == null) {
            System.out.println("SplashScreen.getSplashScreen() returned 
    null");
            return;
        }
        Graphics2D g = splash.createGraphics();
        if (g == null) {
            System.out.println("g is null");
            return;
        }
   }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
    }

    private static WindowListener closeWindow = new WindowAdapter(){
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e){
            e.getWindow().dispose();
        }
    };

    public static void main (String args[]) {
        Splash test = new Splash();
     }
}
```

Comment: Your problem description lack the important information whether an actual splash screen image (the contents of `Images/Splash.gif`) is visible on the screen. That’s more important than your assertion that “the path to the splash screen is correct”. Seeing an image implies that the JVM agrees with your assertion.

Comment: I could not get your point:'JVM agrees with the assertions'. In my jar i can see a image folder inside which i have a splash screen image file.

Comment: *Do you see an image on the screen?*

Comment: No I am not able to see the image on the screen in my application

Comment: So the problem is not that `getSplashScreen()` returns `null`, but that the splash screen feature doesn’t work at all. That’s why it is so important to be precise about the nature of the problem. If there is no splash screen before your code gets executed, it doesn’t matter what your code attempts to do afterwards.

Comment: Could you tell me what could be the reason for this issue. When i tried the demo available in oracle docs it worked smoothly. But in my application somehow the manifest file's Splash-Screen attribute is not picked by the JVM.

Comment: First, check that the path is correct in the jar, even with a case sensitive comparison, second, check that the application is indeed invoked via the `-jar` option rather than just adding the jar to the class path. The latter might be the problem, as I don’t see any main class attribute in the manifest, which would be required to launch the application with the `-jar` option.

Comment: The invocation is done via an ant script as below.                
     <java fork="true" classname="com.package.main.swing.DealEntryController">
   <jvmarg value="-Dsplash=Images/Splash.gif" />                                                                              Would I need to make any modification for this.                                                                             Also the jar is invoked using a jnlp file and not using the java -jar command. What changes do I need to make in this to get the SPlash screen working(Note in the jnlp file has the main class attribute)

Comment: You are contradicting yourself. Do you launch the application via the ant script or via a jnlp file? In the latter case, I don’t know whether it supports the splash screen feature at all (you’ll have to check the documentation), in the ant case, that script is not using the equivalent to the `-jar` option. In either case, you should [edit] your question rather than elaborating the details in the comments…

Comment: When executing locally ie dev environment we use an ant script.  In prod the jar is invoked by jnlp. Ill edit my question to splash screen not working when invoked via jnlp. Woul that be fine?